# Display object label (using blenderGIS addon) in final render

Tags: objects, add-on, text-object

I'm using the blenderGIS addon for some bathymetry data to show to clients with sample locations. It's brilliant but I have a small problem.

I can fix it manually but it's tedious when there are many many objects.

Each object needs a label, when I import the objects they're named as I want to display them so by:

Clicking on the object then going on the menu >object>display and ticking "name" they're all labelled in the 3D viewport.

Each label faces the camera at all times. However I can't find an option to display them in the **final render**

Is the only way to manually create text for each object and get them to face the camera?

Comment: Did you find an easy solution?

Comment: I did! Thanks to this guy https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101077/how-do-i-get-object-names-to-appear-in-the-render