# Is it possible to add a hovering informative textbox?

Tags: text-object

I'm really new to blender and don't really know whats possible in it. So Is it possible to add a hovering informative textbox?

Like I'm making this school project and we want to have a 3d model of our object in question and I was wondering if its possible to add text boxes that face the camera at all times that have a line drawn to a certain point of the object? We will not be showcasing the item on blender, but an online obj viewer.

Very roughly drawn idea of what I mean: https://gyazo.com/b543aa2bc6ceb9bf37e3f8dde3e3bb19

[image]

Comment: Blender doesn't natively do this, though it could be faked with a few constraints. However if you are exporting in OBJ to other applications none of the techniques will survive the port

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101485/29586 - although it would be specific to Blender and wouldn’t export to an external viewer.