# objects in camera space for mockup GUI

Tags: interface, camera, customization, workspaces

I want to use blender for concepting video game UI. I'm looking for a way to have UI elements camera or screen space oriented.

For example there are multiple loot chests in the scene and I want to create UI elements above to display what's inside. Is there a way to have UI elements somehow in camera space instead in the 3d space of that scene? Or is making simple planes with textures and scaling them by eye the only approach?

thank you for your time

Comment: Possibly related (label objects as camera overlay) : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101485/29586